# Bash '.' vs proper dir string

Tags: bash

I have been running a number of find commands and have noticed something that seems odd about how bash handles the `.` vs a dir inputted as a string.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'cd $(dirname "$0") && aunpack "$0"' {} \;
```

acts completely differently to

```
find [current dir] -type f -exec sh -c 'cd $(dirname "$0") && aunpack "$0"' {} \;
```

What gives?

Does bash treat '.' and a string specified directory path differently. Isn't '.' a substitute for the current dir?

Comment: What's the different behavior you are seeing?

Comment: `find` will print out the results with relative path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What `find` does is append the rest of the path to the location passed as an argument.

Ie: if you are in dir "/home/user/find":

```
find .
```

Prints:

```
.
./a
./b
```

But if you try:

```
find /home/user/find
```

It prints:

```
/home/user/find
/home/user/find/a
/home/user/find/b
```

So `find` appends the rest of the path (/a, /b...) to the argument (. or /home/user/find).

Comment: If I had the rep I'd vote you up so fast. That 100% explains the 'strange' behaviour I was seeing between . and $(pwd)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `pwd` command instead of the `.` and it will behave the same.

```
find "`pwd`"  -type f -exec sh -c 'cd $(dirname "$0") && aunpack "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: Awesome. At the moment my bash scripting is both rusty and mostly to do with my new website project. I'm so used to using python for everything scripting related its very awkward to try coming back to to shell scripting for increased portability for this work.

Answer (score 2):

@arutaku has pinpointed the source of the problem; let me point out another possible solution. If your version of `find` supports it, the `-execdir` primary does what you want very simply: it cd's to the directory each file is in, then executes the command with just the filename (no path):

```
find . -type f -execdir aunpack {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash has nothing to do with it, it's the logic of `find`. It does not try to expand or normalize the path(s) *you* give, it just uses them verbatim: not only for `.` but for any path specification (e.g. `../../my/other/project`).

I find it reasonable because any conversion would be more complicated than the current behavior. At least we would have to remember if symbolic links are resolved during conversion. And whenever we *want* a relative path for some reason, we would have to relativize it again.